# Sapper back button not working after history pushstate function

Tags: svelte, sapper

I'm using following versions of Sapper and Svelte:

```
"sapper": "^0.27.0",
"svelte": "^3.0.0"
```

After updating the url using `history.pushState()` function, and then navigating to other page. The back button is not taking back to the url changed by `history.pushState()`

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `history.pushState()` — that's the equivalent of doing your own `element.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))` in Svelte. Instead, use Sapper's `goto` function: https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#goto_href_options

Comment: Right. I was actually trying to change url on ``input`` field change.

Comment: I used ``goto(`/profile/edit?id=${profile_id}`, { replaceState: true })``. I'm getting the desired results but losing the focus of form field. How can my field remain focus after ``goto()`` with ``replaceState``?

Comment: How do you import the goto function.

Comment: @YousufIqbalHashim you would presumably need to keep a reference to the form element and set the focus programmatically, or use `autofocus` if it's a new element.

Comment: @JoshuaUchennaAmaju `import { goto } from '@sapper/app'`

Comment: I tried that earlier, but I got a warning saying that I shouldn't import from sapper. And I think the app crashed at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue with sapper https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/issues/791

The workaround mentioned is to pass `{id:0}` as *data* to the `history.pushState()`. For example

```
history.pushState({id:0}, '', url)
```

**But beware!**, we don't know the consequences of doing that